# That's a lot of red lines

Tags: support, google-chrome, spelling

Just before clicking "add comment", I was checking the text for the red underlined spelling errors.  But there were a lot of red lines.  Now English is not my native language, but I'm pretty sure that "very" is not a typo?

[image]

The screenshot is from Chrome.  I get a lot of red lines while posting this question too (including "too", haha) so it might be Chrome related.

Comment: That's a chrome issue -- nothing in the SO code produces those red underlines. This belongs on SuperUser ;-)

Comment: Why was this voted down? It is a very clear and concise question, with a screenshot to boot. It doesn't matter that it *turned out* to be a Chrome issue, it *appears* to be an SO one.

Comment: @devinb, may be because not yet friday? :)

Comment: Says your location's the Netherlands - you're probably using a non-English dictionary.  Or an English dictionary that's horribly messed up...

Comment: Now I'm wondering what "the" means in Dutch... or "Definitely" :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

May be you need to install dictionary for spell-checking

[How can I install additional dictionaries for Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/142379/how-can-i-install-additional-dictionaries-for-chrome)

Comment: Changing the spell checking language in Chrome's options fixed this.  And I thought it was a neat StackOverflow JavaScript that added the wavy lines!  Thanks.

Comment: Oh ok, spell checking need reasonably big dictionary, so doing through javascript is overkill, most will not do that. :)

Answer (score 2):

That's an issue with Chrome, not with Stack Overflow. Not sure why that's happening. Did you update to the newest edition of Chrome?

Comment: Help->About says it's up-to-date.  Version 4.1.249.1064.  As a practical matter, it's up to StackOverflow to make sure it works in Chrome, not the other way round ;)

Comment: @Andomar: No, StackOverflow has absolutely nothing to do with those red lines. That's purely Chrome and there's nothing the SO team can do about them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using Chrome (4.1.249.1064 (45376)) but cannot reproduce:
[image]
<sub>(source: [sampsonresume.com](http://sampsonresume.com/labs/stackoverflow/chrome-red-lines.JPG))</sub>